# How to display image href from db collection as an actual image

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I using jQuery to access an image href in database collection i.e https://somesite/img/somePhoto.png and then display this in a divtag.

I have made it to the point where I can display the text of the href, but I now want to take this a step further and actually display the image itself.

.html(message.media) is the element I am trying to display as an image

Here is the code so far

```
groupManager.prototype.displayChatMessage = function( message ){
    var _this = this;
    $('<li/>')
        .attr("id",message._id)
        .text(message.message) //message text
        .html(message.media) // https://somesite/img/somePhoto.png
        .prepend($("<strong />").text(message.fromName+': '))
        .appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
    $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
};
```

Comment: Please consider using more advance technique like AngularJS or React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this hope it will work.

```
groupManager.prototype.displayChatMessage = function( message ){
   var _this = this;
   var html = '<li id="'+ message._id +'">';
   html += '<p>'+ message.message +'</p>'; // you can use different tag.
   html += '<img src="' + message.media + '" />';
   html += '<strong >' + message.fromName + '</strong>';
   html += '</li>';
   $('#messagesDiv').append(html);
   $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
};
```

Comment: This works.  I will have to modify it somewhat but it displays a photo.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the href value, add it to the href `<a href=""></a>`.

Example:

```
$('a').attr('href', 'YOUR HREF VALUE');
```

Answer (score 0):

check below example

```js
var _this = this;
message = {message: 'abc', media: 'http://www.lets-develop.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/How-to-change-img-src-with-jQuery-change-img-url.jpg', fromName: 'ans'}
    $('<li/>')
        .attr("id",message._id)
        .text(message.message) //message text
        .html('<img src="'+message.media+'">') // https://somesite/img/somePhoto.png
        .prepend($("<strong />").text(message.fromName+': '))
        .appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
    $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messagesDiv">

</div>
```